# The given relation is not equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

A relation $R$ is defined on the set of integers as follows: 
$$(a,b)\in R\iff a^b=b^a$$

Clearly, it is reflexive and symmetric. But I am unable to give a counter example that it is not transitive.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you characterize the pairs of integers that fulfill $\;a^b=b^a\;$ There aren't many...

Comment: I found $\{(a,a), a\in \mathbb{Z}\}, (2,4), (4,2)$

Comment: @Sa Well, also $\;(-2,-4)\;,\;\;(-4,-2)\;$ ...and thus you already know **all** the cases for which there is any need to check symmetry... :)

Comment: Can you find *any* other examples.  If those are the only two then $a R b$ and $b R c$ means either $a =b$ or $b=c$ or it means $(a,b),(b,c) = (2,4)(4,2)$.

Comment: It means that it is transitive.

Comment: *if* (2,4) and (4,2) are the only examples (I haven't verified it but I believe it to be true) then a R b and b R c has either a=b and b= c so a R c.  Or it has one of a R b or b R c being either 2 R 4 or 4R 2 and the other being 4R4 or 2R2 in which case a R c or you have (ab) being (2,4) or (4,2) and bc being (4,2) or (24) and a = c.

Comment: But it doesn't matter... even if 2^7 = 7^2 and 7^9 = 9^7 as answered below, 2^9 = 7^{2/7)^9 = (7^9)^{2/7} = (9^7)^{2/7} = 9^2 so it would still be transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume
$$a^b=b^a $$
and
$$b^c=c^b $$

then

$$a^c=b^{\frac {a}{b}c} $$

$$c^a=b^{\frac {c}{b}a} $$

which yields to
$$a^c=c^a$$

Comment: How you have written $a^c=b^{\frac {a}{b}c}$?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad $b^{\frac{a}{b}c}=a^{\frac{b}{b}c}=a^c$

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad from the first , $a=b^{a/b} $ and $a^c=(b^{a/b})^c $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima See $a=b^{a/b}$ says that $a$ may not be an integer. But its given that $a,b,c$ are integers.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad For integers the unique solution is $2^4=4^2$.

Comment: Okay, but why it is not transitive. As given in the book that it is not transitive.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad It is transitive.

Comment: @SahibaArora Can you prove that it is transitive?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad The above answer proves it.

Comment: But that is not correct as $a=b^{a/b}$ implies that $a$ may be a non-integer.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes. it is transitive as proved above.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad No. You are already saying that $a$ is an integer. This implies that $b^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is an integer.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad I poved that if a^b=b^a and b^c=c^b then a^c=c^a in integers or not.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Let me think for a moment.

Comment: "See a=ba/b says that a may not be an integer. But its given that a,b,c are"  It doesn't mater that a/b is not an integer as we are not saying anything about R at that step.